# How to Redriect the my page when user click on my Business Related Web Part title?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, web-part

I want to Redirect the my page when user click on web part title.
This is  Business Related Web Part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to

Edit Web part > Below Advanced Section > Add your redirect URL at `Title URL` Text Box.

**Note:** Title URL is a [Common property for all Business Data Web Parts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-Business-Data-Web-Parts-6ebda742-7563-43a5-9d68-136a00cd4121#__toc315766647)

[image]

Comment: adding # in `Title URL` will redirect user to the home page.

Comment: no my bro this my current value , i mentioned to him to add his redirect uel at this

Comment: let me check again at my end again. I checked it redirected to home page.

Comment: @AakashMorya # is denoted to unlinkable value , but I told him to add his link that he need at this value as He needs . he doesn't say which his destination Url , so i told him put it here :)

Comment: Got it worked. I got the question wrong. Its working :-)

Comment: Hey it work i want to redirect my other page. I add the my url in Title URL text box. Thank You.